# Specialization Function Calls from other functions

Tags: c++, templates, specialization

I am trying to figure out to call a template specialization function from another. In the following short segment, I am trying to call the BLACK specific function from the RED. I get the following compiler error

cannot call member function `bool noClass<color>::_open() [with Colors color = (Colors)2]’ without object`

which makes perfect sense. How can (or can I) make the call to the BLACK from RED work? The code segment is below from the noClass C++ header.

```
#ifndef COLORS_H
#define COLORS_H

enum class Colors { RED, GREEN, BLACK };

#endif /* COLORS_H */

#ifndef NOCLASS_H
#define NOCLASS_H


    template <Colors color> 
    class noClass {
        public: bool Open ( );
        protected: bool _open ( );
    };

    template <Colors color> bool noClass<color>::Open ( ) { return noClass<color>::_open ( ); }

    template <Colors color> bool noClass<color>::_open ( ) { return true; }

    template <> inline bool noClass<Colors::BLACK>::_open ( ) { return true; }

    template <> inline bool noClass<Colors::RED>::_open ( ) { return noClass<Colors::BLACK>::_open( ); }

#endif /* NOCLASS_H */
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't, because you don't have an instance of the required type.  Try writing your common code in a helper function and having both specializations call that.

Comment: I was sure that this would be the answer; compilers rarely lie. On the other hand, there are some VERY clever people out there and I figured what the hell, doesn't hurt to ask. Wish I could up the "Answer is useful" but as a recent registree I'm not allowed. Thanks!!

Comment: @NonSequitur: The function you are trying to call is a non-static member function, it therefore has a "hidden this" parameter which must be bound to an instance of `noClass<Colors::BLACK>`.  And different instantiations of the same template are not related (not even if their type template parameters are related by inheritance -- C++ templates aren't covariant).  It IS possible to have one template specialization inherit from another, but that doesn't feel like a good solution here.  You might consider making a common base class to hold shared implementation.  Have a look at CRTP

Comment: which stands for Curiously Recurring Template Pattern.  It allows a shared implementation in a base class to access members of the derived classes.

Comment: Would somehow using the copy constructor (if there was one) be a possible solution?